# Background-image not appearing on site copy, despite identical source & CSS files?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me why [this site](http://www.sydneypadua.com/betatesting/) has a background-image on the header, and [this site](http://sydneypadua.com/2dgoggles/) does not - despite virtually identical source and CSS files?

In the first one, the style is being picked up correctly, and in the second it isn't. But there is no obvious reason why this is the case.

Help!

Thank you :)

Comment: How do the sites have virtually identical CSS files?  I don't see a background image being set on the second page.  Can you post the CSS fragments on the two sites that you're referring to?

Comment: the first one takes the background image from a css file named dynamik.css but the second doesn't link it. If that's helpful

Comment: if you do 'inspect element' on the header on the second site, you will see the styles that are being applied, and a link to the CSS file... and that file seems to have a background-image style for that ID in it... unless I'm being very stupid :(

Comment: the second one points at http://sydneypadua.com/2dgoggles/wp-content/themes/2dgoggles/style.css, which sets a background-image style on the #header-left element - in the same way as the first, it's just a different CSS filename. I think!

Comment: @AP257, when you say "the header", which element ID/class do you refer to?  `#header-wrap`, `#header`, and `#header-left` don't seem to have a background image set.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem.  See my answer.

Comment: #header-left. Sorry, should have clarified a bit more in the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector that's trying to set the background image looks like this:

```
.logo-image #header #header-left
```

Since `#header` is not a descendent of `.logo-image`, those styles do not get applied.  If, however, the selector was changed to just:

```
#header #header-left
```

or even

```
#header-left
```

Then it should work (assuming the image URL is good).

**Update:**

I didn't see the `.logo-image` class on the body before, but now it's there.  There may have been some sort of *caching* (wink) issue in place.

Comment: That's the first thing I thought too - but it is! The `logo-image` class is there on `<body>`, just as it is on the first site - where the background-image does appear.

Comment: Oh, it's up! It was just caching differently. Thank you anyway - if you like, update your answer to say 'caching' and I'll accept it :)